# "proper client ssl certificate was not presented" postman error

Tags: api, ssl, postman, adp

My postman request errors-out with status: 401 Unauthorized and "error_description": "proper client ssl certificate was not presented".

I have confirmed in both MMC and MS Edge that ADP certificate is installed - it shows-up in a list of certificates.  The status of certificate reads - "This certificate is OK", "Windows does not have enough information to verify this certificate".

Can this cause the Postman error?  What else should I pay attention to?

I'm following [Making Your First API Call Using Postman](https://developers.adp.com/articles/general/make-your-first-api-call-using-postman-1) directions and trying to request a bearer token from ADP.